# Null value for the foreign key relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am creating a simple register module. I was able to successfully insert data via SQL Management studio but when tried to run the application, it is getting a null value ref. UserxId is 0 but the configuration is set to Identity and i'm not sure why AccessLevel is null. The code is very straightforward and unitofwork and generic repository is standard.

Property:

```
public class Userx
    {
        public int UserxId { get; set; }
        public int Access_Level_ID { get; set; }
        public virtual AccessLevel AccessLevel { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }


    }
```

Configuration:

```
public class UserxConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Userx>
    {
        public UserxConfig()
        {
            ToTable("Userx");
            HasKey(x => new { x.UserxId, x.Access_Level_ID });

            Property(x => x.UserxId)
                .HasColumnName("UserxId")
                .HasColumnType(SqlDbType.Int.ToString())
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            Property(x => x.Access_Level_ID)
             .HasColumnName("Access_Level_ID")
             .HasColumnType(SqlDbType.Int.ToString())
             .IsRequired();

            HasRequired(x => x.AccessLevel)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.Access_Level_ID)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        }
    }
```

Below is the code for the controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Registers(Userx userx)
        {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
                    {
                        var encryptedPw = CustomEncrypt.Encrypt(userx.password);
                        var user = new Userx
                        {
                            Access_Level_ID = userx.Access_Level_ID,
                            username = userx.username,
                            password = userx.password
                        };
                        _unitOfWork.UserxRepository.Insert(user);
                        _unitOfWork.Save();
                        scope.Complete();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "One or more fields have been");
                }

            return View();
        }
```

The view is auto generated.

[sample value while debugging, after the line, null value exception appears.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApSNN.png)

Basically I have two questions,

1. Why was the UserxId 0 when in fact it should be auto generated and auto incremented
2. Should the AccessLevel have value? I believe that property is used to map the foreign key.

Update:
Property for AccessLevel:

```
public class AccessLevel
    {
        public int Access_Level_ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Level { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Configuration:

```
public class AccessLevelConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<AccessLevel>
    {
        public AccessLevelConfig()
        {
            ToTable("AccessLevel");
            HasKey(x => x.Access_Level_ID);

            Property(x => x.Access_Level_ID)
                .HasColumnName("Access_Level_ID")
                .HasColumnType(SqlDbType.Int.ToString())
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        }
    }
```

DataContext:

```
public DbSet<AccessLevel> AccessLevel { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Userx> Userx { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AccessLevelConfig());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserxConfig());
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

[Null Value Reference Exception Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ECSS.png)

**FIX:**
The UserxRepository was returning the null value ref. exception.

Before:

```
 private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

       public AuthController(UnitOfWork unitOfWork;)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }
```

After:

```
private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

       public AuthController()
        {
            _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork;
        }
```

What i was trying to accomplish on the before code was to create an abstraction by having **UnitOfWork** dependency class in the constructor so the object will be pre-instantiated.

Comment: Id for an entity is assgined after saving IIRC.

Comment: Okay, How about the AccessLevel? I dont think it should have a value but it's throwing a null exception. Do you happen to know what value should be passed?

Comment: `Access_Level_ID` is a foreign key, meaning that if you set it to some value, Entity Framework will check if there is an `AccessLevel` entity with this ID (2 in the provided screenshot). Do you have such entity in your database? If yes, please provide the details (message, type) of the exception as at the moment I can't seem to find another explanation

Comment: Hi @JakubJankowski I have added more details. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: to me it would appear there is the value null (userx) passed to the Registers() method or Userxrepository is null.

Comment: @vaughnellisramos
Is the `UserxRepository` in `_unitOfWork` assigned properly (is not `null`)? Also, if you could copy and paste the stacktrace of the exception, that would provide me some insight, the screenshot cuts off the most important part of it.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro thank you! tried to debug the userxrepository and correct, it is the one that is returning a null value exception. I will edit so you can see the fix

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Userx
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] //TELL EF TO AUTOGENERATE ID
        public int UserxId { get; set; }
        public int? Access_Level_ID { get; set; } //MAKE ACCESS_LEVEL_ID NULLABLE
        public virtual AccessLevel AccessLevel { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This is already been done on the DbConfiguration. screenshot 2. Difference is you just used Data Annotation. Tried to make Access_Level_ID nullable but encountered the same issue.

Answer (score -2):

Define Primary Key to Userx table on UserxId. It will automatically generate auto increment identity.

```
public class Userx
    {
        [Key] //TELL EF TO AUTOGENERATE ID
        public int UserxId { get; set; }
        public int? Access_Level_ID { get; set; } //MAKE ACCESS_LEVEL_ID NULLABLE
        public virtual AccessLevel AccessLevel { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
```